# How to plot a formula with a given range?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, range, formula

I am looking to plot the following:

```
L<-((2*pi*h*c^2)/l^5)*((1/(exp((h*c)/(l*k*T)-1))))
```

all variables except `l` are constant:

```
T<-6000
h<-6.626070040*10^-34
c<-2.99792458*10^8
k<-1.38064852*10^-23
```

`l` has a range of `20*10^-9` to `2000*10^-9`.

I have tried `l<-seq(20*10^-9,2000*10^-9,by=1*10^-9)`, however this does not give me the results I expect.

Is there a simple solution for this in R, or do I have to try in another language?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't really say what you want or how the output you get differs from the desired one

Comment: "however this does not give me the results I expect" -- *how* did you try to use this and how does it differ from what you expect? Please give a [mcve]. Also -- using a lower-case "L" as a variable is often considered a poor choice since it is too easy to confuse with the number 1.

Comment: Do you just need to plot the function or do you need the range of values of `L` as a vector (for example, to do further operations)?

Comment: With numbers that small, you are going to have severe problems with numerical stability. You probably need a better algorithm rather than a different language.

Comment: The value of my output is about 1000 times higher than expected. When I do the above, I do get a plot, however the numbers are off. I have checked every other variable, so I believe that possibly missunderstanding how "seq" works and not knowing an alternative to assign a range of numbers to a variable is leading to this problem. Edit: I just need to plot "L". "L" is suppsed to be the result of Planck's law, "L<-((2*pi*h*c^2)/l^5)*((1/(exp((h*c)/(l*k*T)-1))))" is the equasion.

Comment: At a minimum, give the unstated values of the constants and the sequence of commands you use to generate the plot. `seq` is unlikely to be the issue. Your `l` consists of the 1981 values: `2.0e-08, 2.1e-08, ..., 1.999e-06, 2.000e-06`

Comment: T<-6000  
h<-6.626070040*10^-34  
c<-2.99792458*10^8  
k<-1.38064852*10^-23  

are my constants, my attempts to plot "L" consist of the plot() command while adding only visual parameters.

Comment: The reason I suspect "seq()" to be the problem is that when I input 20*10^-9 or 2000*10^-9 into "L" i get results closer to what I expect.

Comment: Examine `l` in the console. It does consist of roughly 2000 values which are evenly distributed between your stated endpoints. I don't think that is the issue. I think that you are dealing with the fact that floating-point accuracy breaks down with very large and very small numbers. Perhaps you could rescale by changing units. Or, perhaps you could first compute `log(L)` and then exponentiate.

Comment: Thank you, I'll attept both of your suggestions.

Comment: I don't really know the physics, but your `l` seems to be a wave length. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) on Planck's Law has fairly reasonable graphs when `l` is measured in micrometres. Perhaps that might be a reasonable choice of units rather than what you are currently using (meters?).

Comment: Yes "l" is a wave length, nanometers and micrometers can both be used, the formula works best when using basic SI-units (meters^-9 in this case). I am perfectly happy with the form of the graph I get, it's the too high values that bother me, what I am looking for is basically the blue graph here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#/media/File:Black_body.svg just with a higher maximum. Working on the scale of the axes might do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [spectral radiance equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) wikipedia page, it seems that your formula is a bit off. Your formula multiplies an additional `pi` (not sure if intended) and the `-1` is inside the `exp` instead of outside:

```
L <- ((2*pi*h*c^2)/l^5)*((1/(exp((h*c)/(l*k*T)-1))))
```

Below is the corrected formula. Also notice I have converted it into a function with parameter `l` since this is a variable:

```
T <- 6000                # Absolute temperature
h <- 6.626070040*10^-34  # Plank's constant
c <- 2.99792458*10^8     # Speed of light in the medium
k <- 1.38064852*10^-23   # Boltzmann constant

L <- function(l){((2*h*c^2)/l^5)*((1/(exp((h*c)/(l*k*T))-1)))}

# Plotting
plot(L, xlim = c(20*10^-9,2000*10^-9),
     xlab = "Wavelength (nm)",
     ylab = bquote("Spectral Radiance" ~(KW*sr^-1*m^-2*nm^-1)),
     main = "Plank's Law",
     xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")
xtick <- seq(20*10^-9, 2000*10^-9,by=220*10^-9)
ytick <- seq(0, 4*10^13,by=5*10^12)
axis(side=1, at=xtick, labels = (1*10^9)*seq(20*10^-9,2000*10^-9,by=220*10^-9))
axis(side=2, at=ytick, labels = (1*10^-12)*seq(0, 4*10^13,by=5*10^12))
```

[image]

The plot above is not bad, but I think we can do better with `ggplot2`:

```
h <- 6.626070040*10^-34  # Plank's constant
c <- 2.99792458*10^8     # Speed of light in the medium
k <- 1.38064852*10^-23   # Boltzmann constant

L2 <- function(l, T){((2*h*c^2)/l^5)*((1/(exp((h*c)/(l*k*T))-1)))} # Plank's Law
classical_L <- function(l, T){(2*c*k*T)/l^4} # Rayleigh-Jeans Law

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(l = c(20*10^-9,2000*10^-9)), aes(l)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=390*10^-9, xmax=700*10^-9, ymin=0, ymax=Inf), 
            alpha = 0.3, fill = "lightblue") +
  stat_function(fun=L2, color = "red", size = 1, args = list(T = 3000)) +
  stat_function(fun=L2, color = "green", size = 1, args = list(T = 4000)) +
  stat_function(fun=L2, color = "blue", size = 1, args = list(T = 5000)) +
  stat_function(fun=L2, color = "purple", size = 1, args = list(T = 6000)) +
  stat_function(fun=classical_L, color = "black", size = 1, args = list(T = 5000)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(20*10^-9, 2000*10^-9,by=220*10^-9),
                     labels = (1*10^9)*seq(20*10^-9,2000*10^-9,by=220*10^-9),
                     sec.axis = dup_axis(labels = (1*10^6)*seq(20*10^-9,2000*10^-9,by=220*10^-9),
                                         name = "Wavelength (\U003BCm)")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 4*10^13,by=5*10^12),
                     labels = (1*10^-12)*seq(0, 4*10^13,by=5*10^12),
                     limits = c(0, 3.5*10^13)) +
  labs(title = "Black Body Radiation described by Plank's Law", 
       x = "Wavelength (nm)",
       y = expression("Spectral Radiance" ~(kWsr^-1*m^-2*nm^-1)),
       caption = expression(''^'\U02020' ~'Spectral Radiance described by Rayleigh-Jeans Law, which demonstrates the ultraviolet catastrophe.')) +
  annotate("text", 
           x = c(640*10^-9, 640*10^-9, 640*10^-9, 640*10^-9, 
                 150*10^-9, (((700-390)/2)+390)*10^-9, 1340*10^-9), 
           y = c(2*10^12, 5*10^12, 14*10^12, 31*10^12, 
                 35*10^12, 35*10^12, 35*10^12), 
           label = c("3000 K", "4000 K", "5000 K", "6000 K", 
                    "UV", "VISIBLE", "INFRARED"),
           color = c(rep("black", 4), "purple", "blue", "red"),
           alpha = c(rep(1, 4), rep(0.6, 3)),
           size = 4.5) +
  annotate("text", x = 1350*10^-9, y = 23*10^12, 
           label = deparse(bquote("Classical theory (5000 K)"^"\U02020")),
           color = "black", parse = TRUE)
```

**Notes:**

1. I created `L2` by also making absolute temperature `T` a variable
2. For each `T`, I plot the function `L2` using different colors for representation. I've also added a `classical_L` function to demonstrate classical theory of spectral radiance
3. `geom_rect` creates the light blue shaded area for "VISIBLE" light wavelength range
4. `scale_x_continuous` sets the breaks of the x axis, while `labels` sets the axis tick labels. Notice I have multiplied the `seq` by `(1*10^9)` to convert the units to nanometer (nm). A second x-axis is added to display the micrometer scale
5. Analogously, `scale_y_continuous` sets the breaks and tick labels for y axis. Here I multiplied by `(1*10^-12)` or `(1*10^(-3-9))` to convert from watts (W) to kilowatts (kW), and from inverse meter (m^-1) to inverse nanometer (nm^-1)
6. `bquote` displays superscripts correctly in the y axis label
7. `annotate` sets the coordinates and text for curve labels. I've also added the labels for "UV", "VISIBLE" and "INFRARED" light wavelengths

**ggplot2**

[image]

**Plot from wikipedia:**

[image]

Image source: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/19/Black_body.svg/600px-Black_body.svg.png